# How to display a welcome message including username from another activity in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Here is what I want to do, I have an android login form with username and password, after the user enters his credentials and login, the next form should display on top of the page welcome,+username entered from the login page! can someone please help me??

I'm new to android development and don't know how to go about this. Thanks

Comment: intent has `getStringExtra` which will work there is no need o edit my post. i have posted the links to the docs. i am sure it will work. do not edit others post instead comment on their posts

Comment: have a look @ http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getStringExtra(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use intent to pass username from one activity to another.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("username","enteredusername");
startActivity(intent);
```

And in SecondActivity

```
String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("username");
```

Now use the name and display the welcome +name

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Answer (score 0):

In order to send data from one activity to another, you need to use intents. So, in your login activity, you would launch your welcome activity like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, WelcomeActivity.class);
intent.putextra("userName","value");
startActivity(intent);
```

Then, in your welcome activity, you need to retrieve the extra data, like so:

```
String data= getIntent().getStringExtra("userName");
```

There are a multitude of examples that can be found via Google, and many questions similar/identical to this have been answered previously on SO.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the username in sqlite or sharedpreferences to get the username across all your application.